# Reading NFC Tag via Flutter

Tags: flutter, nfc

There is a sensor called "FreeStyle Libre" (https://www.freestylelibre.co.uk/libre/). I want to read this device's data via Flutter but NFC doesn't see this device. I can read via their original app. What could be the problem? Is it encryption problem or something like that? How can I find the problem.

Comment: What NFC App have you tried to read the device with? I would suggest you start with the NXP Taginfo App as that is good at the low level stuff to give you a direction. There are a number of different Tag Types (1-5) and they each have different methods to read, then there could be many different data formats and to add to the complexity there could also be password protection and encryption, so reverse engineering it could be very difficult. The easiest way is to get the datasheet of how to communicate with the device from the maker.

Comment: How can I learn the type of nfc

Comment: As I said use the  NXP Taginfo App